# Health Check modification in OpenShift 3.11

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

I need to temporarly disable a Liveness Probe in a production environment on Openshift 3.11.
Is it necessary to re-deploy the pods or is it a hot-plug modification?

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there is no feature at the moment to disable probes dynamically.
Look this discussion for more details, https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/57187
If you want to disable it, you need to redeploy the pod without probes config.

Comment: thanx for your answer, I will plan a redeploy